# Dont show if field is left blank

Tags: php

This is the code that shows a Manufacturer Part Number on my product listing

```
<span class="p-rewards">MPN:<?php echo $text_mpn; ?></span> <?php echo $mpn; ?><br />
```

what I would like to do is not show the MPN: Field on the product page if the `$text_mpn` field is blank, e.g if no part number is listed.

Comment: where is your code ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
<?php if($mpn != ""){ ?>
  <span class="p-rewards">MPN:<?php echo $text_mpn; ?></span> <?php echo $mpn; ?><br />
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put an if statement around it. You can close the PHP code block after the if, put your code inbetween and open a new PHP code block to close it:

```
<?php if ($text_mpn != ''){ ?>
<span class="p-rewards">MPN:<?php echo $text_mpn; ?></span> <?php echo $mpn; ?><br />
<?php };>
```

For blocks like this, it can be a bit messy and unclear to see where the block ends if you use normal curly braces, so you might consider the [Alternative syntax for control structures](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) for these cases:

```
<?php if ($text_mpn != ''):?>
<span class="p-rewards">MPN:<?php echo $text_mpn; ?></span> <?php echo $mpn; ?><br />
<?php endif;>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```html
<?php if(strlen($text_mpn) > 0) echo "<span class='p-rewards'>MPN:".$text_mpn."</span>".$mpn."</br>"; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Case 1:
 You can use empty() for check is variable is empty or not.**

```
<?php if(empty($mpn)){ ?>
<span class="p-rewards">MPN:<?php echo $text_mpn; ?></span> <?php echo $mpn; ?><br />
<?php } ?>
```

**Case :2**

You can simply use `display:none` if you wants to hide control.you can simply add attribute of style.

```
  <div <?php if(empty($mpn))
    { echo 'style="display:none"';}
   else {echo 'style="display:block"';}
    ?> >
    <span class="p-rewards">MPN:<?php echo $text_mpn; ?></span> <?php echo $mpn; ?><br />
 </div>
```

Comment: WOW i had no idea there was so many ways to do this :) I also display a countdown timer on my product page, this is part of the code <div  class="cdbox";><span class="cdbox_2";><img src="../image/data/delivery_van_sml.png"></span><span class="cdbox_0";>Order Within the next&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><br><span id="countdownTimer">00:00.<small>00</small></span>   <p><span class="cdbox_1";>We guarantee same-day Shipping (Monday&nbsp;&#45;&nbsp;Friday) Before 4pm</p></span></div></script>

Comment: how do i hide this if quantity is zero my website is running opencart

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
$mpn = 'Ram Pukar';
$text_mpn = 'Hello ';
echo $text = !empty($mpn) ? '<span class="p-rewards">MPN: '.$text_mpn.'</span>'.$mpn.'<br />':null;
?>
```

Output:

> MPN: Hello Ram Pukar